# Problema de referências

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp, .net-core

Estou estudando .net-core e estou tentando fazer um sistema para um hospital utilizando padrão DDD e .net-core.

Logo quando comecei a criar meus modelos e views, me deparei com um problema de referência quando fui utilizar a tag helper "asp-items"...

O que eu estou esquecendo?

Model
[image: Model]

View
[image: View]

Comment: Inclua o código e não por imagem, só com as informações presentes na pergunta não é possível concluir "nada". Apresente um [MCVE]

Comment: Ps.: Experimente colocar o mouse em cima do trecho sublinhado e ler o que aparece no "Quick Actions" (lampadinha)

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim, consegui! Eu havia esquecido de importar a model somente... Obg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe,

Veja a documentação:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.getenumselectlist?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Sexo é uma entidade/model pelo modelo.